# How to extract the trend component from TBATS forecast?

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using tbats function from forecast package in R. tbats.components function enables us to extract different components from a model object. However, I was not able to find any solution to extract trend component after I make the forecast. That is, I am looking for solutions to get trend forecast component.

Below are the codes examples:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- tbats(USAccDeaths)
```

the following is used to extract components

```
comp = tbats.components(fit);
trend_comp = comp[, 'level']
```

## Making prediction, and this would give the forecast on target variable.

```
pred = forecast(fit, h = 10)
```

My question would be: is it possible to get trend component from pred? i.e. trend forecast.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tbats.components`

```
library(forecast)
out <- tbats.components(fit)
out[, "slope"]
```

It also depends on how the model was created.

#### data

```
fit <- tbats(USAccDeaths, use.trend = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is providing fitted trend component. But what I am looking for is trend forecast component.

Comment: @grapezhu please show a small reproducible example by editing your post. thanks